# Visual Studio requires Rebuild Solution when I change my IronPython scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ironpython

I have a large C# project which includes a number of IronPython scripts.  These scripts are called using the Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting facility.  Within the Visual Studio solution the Python scripts are all kept in their own Project.

If I edit one of the scripts and Run the solution, all my C# code is compiled as needed but the IronPython code is from before my edits.  To force the compiler to use my new scripts I need to use Build | Rebuild Solution.

Is there some way to instruct the compiler to consider and recompile the IronPython scripts when the solution is run?